# Format string with MaskFormatter throws "Invalid character" exception

Tags: java, intellij-idea, maskformatter

I have a function in which I need to set a string to the following format : #####-####-## and padded with leading zeroes.

eg:

`1234567` will become `00001-2345-67`

`98765432109` will become `98765-4321-09`

I'm using [MaskFormatter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/MaskFormatter.html) and my impression from the documentation was that `A` represented any letter or digit, and that `setPlaceHolderCharacter` would pad the string.

I know technically it's for use with text fields but had hoped I could use it in a back-end function, if not is there a different component i should be using?

I have this code below but it throws an exception `java.text.ParseException: Invalid character: 1` when it hits `mask.valueToString(ndc)`

```
public class NdcFormatter implements MapFunction<Purchase, Purchase> {

    private final String maskFormat = "AAAAA-AAAA-AA";
    private final Character placeholder = '0';


    @Override
    public Purchase map(Purchase purchase) throws ParseException {
        if(purchase != null){

            String ndc = purchase.getNdc();
            MaskFormatter mask = new MaskFormatter(maskFormat);
            mask.setPlaceholderCharacter(placeholder);
            String result = mask.valueToString(ndc);

            purchase.setNdc(result);

        }

        return purchase;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is how to fix **ERROR** `java.text.ParseException: Invalid character: ...`  in `MaskFormatter`

**Solution** the error is in `valueToString` method, you have to add this line of code :

```
mask.setValueContainsLiteralCharacters(false);
```

but you will get a problem like that :

- when you set `1234567` it will return you `12345-6700-00`
- to get `00001-2345-67` you have to pass `00001234567`

so you have to fix your input value before formatting .

here is the complete code :

```
public class NdcFormatter implements MapFunction<Purchase, Purchase> {

    private final String maskFormat = "AAAAA-AAAA-AA";
    private final Character placeholder = '0';


    @Override
    public Purchase map(Purchase purchase) throws ParseException {
        if(purchase != null){

            String ndc = purchase.getNdc();
            MaskFormatter mask = new MaskFormatter(maskFormat);
            mask.setPlaceholderCharacter(placeholder);
            mask.setValueContainsLiteralCharacters(false);
            String result = mask.valueToString(ndc);

            purchase.setNdc(result);

        }

        return purchase;
    }
}
```

to pad the leading zeroes by yourself here is a simple code example.

```
    if(ndc.length() < maskFormat.length()) {
        String pad = "0";
        for(int i = 0; i < maskFormat.length() -ndc.length() - 3; i++ ) {
            pad = pad + "0" ;
        }
        ndc = pad + ndc;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, if I understand you correctly I will need to pad the leading zeroes myself?

Comment: yes exactly but at least you have no more error like this : java.text.ParseException: Invalid character: ...